# How to change the data series for highchart using a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is my first time using highcharts js and I'm trying to make a bar chart in which the user can change the data shown in the chart by selecting the data series from a drop down list. My code is below. The chart is graphing fine, but is not responding to the drop down list.

```js
var dataOptions = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Word Count'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Data input from CSV'
  },

  data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('one').innerHTML
  },

  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    lineWidth: 1
  }, {
    color: '#c4392d',
    negativeColor: '#5679c4',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
  }]
}
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(dataOptions);

$("#chartType").change(function() {
  var selVal = $("#chartType").val();
  if (selVal == '0' || selVal == 'one') {
    data: {
      csv: document.getElementById('one').innerHTML
    }
  }
  else {
    data: {
      csv: document.getElementById('two').innerHTML
    }
  }
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(dataOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<select id="chartType">
      <option value="0">-select meeting number-</option>
      <option value="one">1st meeting of year</option>
      <option value="two">2nd meeting of year</option>
    </select>
<button id="change">Refresh Table</button>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 620px; max-width:880px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;" class="ChartBox"></div>

<pre id="one" style="display:none">Year,Consensus,Most,Many,Some,Several,A_Number_Of,Few,Couple_Two,One,Total_Counting_Words,Total_Word_Count
    2003,15,0,0,3,0,3,1,0,0,22,
    2004,17,0,2,4,1,2,3,0,1,30,
    2005,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,
    2006,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,
    2007,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,
    2008,7,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,
    2009,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,7,
    2010,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,12,
    2011,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,9,
    2012,7,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,11,
    2013,10,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,13,
    2014,15,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,
    2015,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,
    2016,11,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,14,</pre>

<pre id="two" style="display:none">Year,Consensus,Most,Many,Some,Several,A_Number_Of,Few,Couple_Two,One,Total_Counting_Words,Total_Word_Count
    2003,15,0,0,3,0,3,1,0,0,40,
    2004,17,0,2,4,1,2,3,0,1,29,
    2005,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,
    2006,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,20,
    2007,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,
    2008,7,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,
    2009,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,7,
    2010,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,12,
    2011,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,9,
    2012,7,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,11,
    2013,10,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,13,
    2014,15,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,
    2015,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,
    2016,11,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,14,</pre>
```

Comment: It does not work because you incorrectly change the data on change event. You should assign your csv object to dataOptions.data - see example http://jsfiddle.net/wg5jafqt/3/

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per [highchart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData) you would be using setData to apply a new set of data to the series and optionally redraw it.

Answer (score 0):

I included the chart object inside the javascript function and it will re-execute every time an action of load or change is triggered.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<select id="chartType">
      <option value="0">-select meeting number-</option>
      <option value="one">1st meeting of year</option>
      <option value="two">2nd meeting of year</option>
    </select>
<button id="change">Refresh Table</button>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 620px; max-width:880px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;" class="ChartBox"></div>

<pre id="one" style="display:none">
    Year,Consensus,Most,Many,Some,Several,A_Number_Of,Few,Couple_Two,One,Total_Counting_Words,Total_Word_Count
    2003,15,0,0,3,0,3,1,0,0,22,
    2004,17,0,2,4,1,2,3,0,1,30,
    2005,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,
    2006,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,5,
    2007,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,
    2008,7,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,
    2009,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,7,
    2010,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,12,
    2011,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,9,
    2012,7,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,11,
    2013,10,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,13,
    2014,15,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,
    2015,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,
    2016,11,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,14,
</pre>

<pre id="two" style="display:none">
    Year,Consensus,Most,Many,Some,Several,A_Number_Of,Few,Couple_Two,One,Total_Counting_Words,Total_Word_Count
    2003,15,0,0,3,0,3,1,0,0,40,
    2004,17,0,2,4,1,2,3,0,1,29,
    2005,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,
    2006,3,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,20,
    2007,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,
    2008,7,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,10,
    2009,5,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,7,
    2010,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,12,
    2011,7,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,9,
    2012,7,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,11,
    2013,10,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,13,
    2014,15,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,
    2015,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,
    2018,11,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,14,
</pre>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#chartType').bind('change rightnow', function () {
  data = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML;
  var selVal = $("#chartType").val();
  console.log(selVal);
  if (selVal == '0' || selVal == 'one') {
    var data = document.getElementById('one').innerHTML;
  }
  else {
    var data = document.getElementById('two').innerHTML;
  }

  var dataOptions = {
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Word Count'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Data input from CSV'
  },
  data: {
    csv: data
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    lineWidth: 1
  }, {
    color: '#c4392d',
    negativeColor: '#5679c4',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
  }]
}
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(dataOptions);

}).triggerHandler("rightnow");
</script>
```